# Firebase Storage Downloadurl Custom Domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, mod-proxy

A part of my firebase app is to serve PDF files on firebase storage to users. When they open those files the bucket downloadurl is visible to all users for example:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project/o/file.PDF?alt=media&token=5btfzb29-f3cf-4557-8741-bfd3f12b1e86I
I want to serve files under:
https://custumdomain.com/file.PDF?alt=media&token=5btfzb29-f3cf-4557-8741-bfd3f12b1e86I
Since I couldn't find any option in my firebase console or cloud storage to achieve this, so I tried to set up a .htaccess redirect.
I tried:
`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://firebasestorage.googleapis/$1 [P]`

The requested document is shown, but the user is also visibly redirected. So my question is divided into 2 parts:
1. Is this the right way to achieve my goal? Is there an easier solution provided by cloud storage? 
2. Why is my proxy flag not working as intended? What do i need to change to hide the redirect?

Comment: just saw this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852804/is-it-possible-to-configure-redirection-with-wildcard-for-firebase-hosting-so-th)

Comment: I tried to make this work by adding "redirects": `[
      {
        "source": "/test*",
        "destination": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com*",
        "type": 302
      }
    ]` to my firebase.json, it could be working but since I'm also using `"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],` for my SPA it seems like the redirect is getting rewritten. can i add an exception/ignore to my rewrite?